# "Jump dictionaries", switch statements, or how to do "jump dictionaries" without eval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, switch-statement, eval

I like the concept of **"jump dictionaries"** that contain key:values, where the values are functions. I'm not sure if I should like this concept or not, though.

I want to replace a long list if `if-else if` statements. (Should I use `switch` statements?)

Is there a way to implement a "jump dictionary" without using eval? 
(I already read this about why eval is bad: 
[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)
)

**Example using eval**

```
function some_func(arg) { console.log('I am a some func') };
function find_my(arg) { console.log('we are looing for your ' + arg); };

var jump = {
    '1' : 'some_func()',
    '2' : 'find_my("cat")',
    '3' : 'find_my("dog")'
}

eval(jump['3'])
eval(jump['2'])
eval(jump['1'])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use anonymous functions:

```
var jump = {
    "1":some_func,
    "2":function() {find_my("cat");},
    "3":function() {find_my("dog");}
}
```

Now you can call:

```
jump["3"]();
jump["2"]();
jump["1"]();
```

Comment: Love it. Time to refactor. Thanks!